# ssh-keyscan stderr comment on success

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I am running a shell script to add fingerprints to known_hosts.

Code is like this:

```
status=$(ssh-keyscan -T 5 $remotehost >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>&1)
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo -n Error: ""
  echo "$status"
  exit 1
fi
```

Result is like this:

```
ssh-keyscan -T 5 example.com
# example.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAA.....o9sgjFlqfli7ZQ==
```

Until recently I had no issues but as of late `ssh-keyscan` adds that comments to the stderr on success and fills my hosts file with garbage. This eventually leads to the hosts file erroring after the same host has been used twice due to a `ssh-keygen -R example.com` command ran ahead to ensure no duplication.

I have been unable to figure out a way to disable that stderr comment.

Answer (score 1):

The original script is (I think) correct except for the order of the redirections.
Swap them round so that first stderr is sent to stdout, then redirect stdout to the file (leaving stderr unchanged). That gives you a clean output file and any errors stored in the variable.

Untested but that's how it should work.

So first line of script should be ...

```
status=$(ssh-keyscan -T 5 $remotehost 2>&1 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts )
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here but changing the  `2>&1` to `2>/dev/null` should do the trick surely.

---

I'd probably do what you want something like this as, as written your $status will never contain anything because you redirect all the output to ~/.ssh/known_hosts

```
ssh-keyscan -T 5 $remotehost >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 2>~/.ssh/error.log
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
  echo -n Error: ""
  cat  ~/.ssh/error.log
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: But in case of an error I can only tell there was one but not get the message.

Comment: @tntu send is to a different file then `2>>error.log`.